# How do we disable editing options on JDateChooser?

Tags: java, swing, validation, jcalendar, jdatechooser

I am using a `JDateChooser` to allow the user to input date. How do I disable editing option on the text field that appears? I would not want the user to type anything in that text field - input should only be entered by clicking from the calendar. How do I achieve that?

Below is my code:

```
public class PQReport {
// product quotations report

public JPanel panel;

public PQReport() {
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 300));
    initUI();

}

public void initUI() {
    panel.setLayout(new net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout());
    JDateChooser chooser = new JDateChooser();
    chooser.setLocale(Locale.US);
    //chooser.isEditable(false);
    chooser.setDateFormatString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    panel.add(new JLabel("Date of Birth:"));
    panel.add(chooser);
    panel.add(new JButton("click"));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            PQReport rep = new PQReport();
            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            f.setSize(400, 400);
            f.setVisible(true);
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.add(rep.panel);

        }
    });
    }
 }
```

Comment: You have to call `setVisible(true)` after you add all the components. Also, call `pack()` instead of `setSize` after adding everything and before displaying.

Comment: A text field is used for input. If you don't want it to be editable, use a `JLabel` instead to display the information. Otherwise, you can call `setEditable(false)`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One approach is to invoke `setEditable(false)` on the chooser's `IDateEditor`, `JTextFieldDateEditor`.

```
JDateChooser chooser = new JDateChooser();
JTextFieldDateEditor editor = (JTextFieldDateEditor) chooser.getDateEditor();
editor.setEditable(false);
```

This allows a new date to be chosen, while forbidding changes via the `JTextField` itself:

[image: set editable false]

The alternative, `chooser.setEnabled(false)`, has the effect of *disabling* the `JDateChooser` entirely.

[image: set enabled false]

Comment: @MadhukaDilhan: Thank you for commenting; while either approach works, I've update the answer to clarify the difference.

Comment: I put your code. it was disable but using chooser can choose the date

Comment: @MadhukaDilhan: Correct; your [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37559448/230513) is a good alternative, if the disabled state is acceptable; I inferred that Giovanrich wanted to preclude _editing the text_, not _changing the date_.

Comment: When disable chooser using chooser.setEnabled(false) it was OK.But it doesn't enable after chooser.setEnabled(true) ..

Comment: Works for me; post a question if you have trouble.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, try this code that disables the `JDateChooser` entirely:

```
JDateChooser chooser = new JDateChooser();
chooser.setEnabled(false);
```

[image]

Comment: This is a valid alternative, but it has a different effect, illustrated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30240464/230513).

Answer (score 1):

You have to put:

```
editor.setEnabled(false);
```

instead of:

```
editor.setEditable(false);
```

So the right code is (I tested it):

```
JDateChooser chooser = new JDateChooser();
JTextFieldDateEditor editor = (JTextFieldDateEditor) chooser.getDateEditor();
editor.setEnabled(false);
```